# SonarQube upgrade 4.2 -> 4.3 UpdateMeasuresDebtToMinutes appears hung

Tags: sonarqube

I'm updating SonarQube on Windows from v4.2 to v4.3 (Windows Server 2008 R2 with MS SQL Server 2008 R2).  All goes well until browsing to the /Setup page and pressing the 'Upgrade' button, after which time the database begins updating, and has not yet completed after more than an hour's processing.

Opening the sonar.log file, I see the last logged migration to begin was 'UpdateMeasuresDebtToMinutes', which began within just a few seconds of the update's initiation.

I'm kind of stuck - SQL Profiler doesn't appear to be giving up much useful information, although it is logging the execution of 'SELECT 1' every few seconds.

If anyone else has had a similar issue, or has any idea how to resolve this problem, I'd sure appreciate some insight.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have set the property 'sonar.technicalDebt.hoursInDay', then this could be similar to this issue : http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Fail-to-migrate-from-SonarQube-4-2-to-4-3-td5024979.html

"If you want to fix this issue, you'll have to apply the modification found here : https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/commit/9ced48150f6570403469d4eaeaaa377e7d0550a4"

Hope it helps.